# Transaction created, but txid not found on blockchain explorers

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, error

Transaction created as same others, but status - 0/unconfirmed
And txid nod found in block explorers 
Transaction ID: e9c858f852a1de7c70e6f8377f2147f3def1d4b1d85a5947d028bb9c13450318

How to succefuly complete this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After opening the RPC debug menu, you can do `getrawtransaction e9c858f852a1de7c70e6f8377f2147f3def1d4b1d85a5947d028bb9c13450318`, and then paste the raw hex transaction to https://www.blockchain.com/btc/pushtx.